# numpy ndenumerate on 2D array with slicing gives incorrect indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Why I am getting incorrect indices while iterating over 2D array with slice using ndenumerate?

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
for idx, x in np.ndenumerate(arr[:, ::2]):
    print(idx, x)
```

Output:

```
(0, 0) 1
(0, 1) 3
(1, 0) 5
(1, 1) 7
```

I think it should give the following output:

```
(0, 0) 1
(0, 2) 3
(1, 0) 5
(1, 2) 7
```

NOTE: Without using slice, I am getting the correct indices.

Comment: `ndenumerate` gets the sliced array, not the original.  Indices are always relative

Comment: `list(np.ndenumerate(arr[:,::2].base))[::2]` gives the output you want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
for idx, x in np.ndenumerate(arr[:, ::2]):
    print(idx, x)
```

you will get:

```
(0, 0) 1
(0, 1) 3
(1, 0) 5
(1, 1) 7
```

because `arr[:, ::2]` is:

```
array([[1, 3],
       [5, 7]])   #ndenumerate will enumerate over this 2X2 array
```

When you do:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
for idx, x in np.ndenumerate(arr):
    print(idx, x)
```

you will get :

```
(0, 0) 1
(0, 1) 2
(0, 2) 3
(0, 3) 4
(1, 0) 5
(1, 1) 6
(1, 2) 7
(1, 3) 8
```

because `arr` is

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])   #ndenumerate will enumerate over this 2X4 array
```